# How to restrict TFS team favorites modification?

Tags: tfs, restrict, favorites

Background:

1. Local standalone instance of TFS 2012 Update 2 deployed from scratch.
2. The Server is Win 2008 R2 SP1 + SQL 2008 R2 + updates (SP2+ I believe)
3. The Server is a member of AD.
4. There is 1 Team and 2 custom groups setup in TFS (developers and testers)
5. Testers are restricted from code and query modifications

Problem:

- How to restrict TFS team favorites from being added/removed by a certain TFS group?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Team favorites can be modified by any member of the team. A team member can modify their own team favorites, but cannot modify another team's team favorites.
There is no way to restrict it more than that.

Comment: So as I understand there are no workarounds at the moment, are there? A pity though, it would be nice to have certain member to manage the favs, and could prevent undesirable occasional edits.